# Find the $\lim\limits_{c \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |g(x) - g(x+c)|dx$

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-integral

Find the 
$$\lim_{c \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  |g(x) - g(x+c)|dx$$
where $g$ is integrable.

I know already that if $g$ is integrable, than the integral of $g(x)$ and the integral of $g(x+c)$ are equal, so I thought perhaps that will help. But to use this I think I would need to split up the integral into two pieces.

Comment: Are there any other given/known properties of $g$?

Comment: No, we just know that g is integrable

Comment: The information given is not enough. For example if g is constant then  the integral is zero. If it is periodic like $\cos x$ the limit might not even exist.

Comment: Hint: Approximate $g$ by a compactly supported integrable function in $L^1$-norm. When $g$ itself is compactly supported, what can you say about the limit?

Comment: @christina_g: Constant function on $\mathbb{R}$ is not integrable (except the constantly zero function).

Comment: You should say "integrable on $\mathbb R$"

Answer (score 0):

Quick Answer: $2\int|g(x)|dx$.

Reason: Note that each integrable function $g$ is essentially compactly
supported, in the sense that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists
$N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\int_{[-N,N]^{c}}|g(x)|dx<\varepsilon$.
If $g$ is compactly supported in the sense that: There exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$
such that $g=0$ on $[-N,N]^{c}$, then obviously $\lim_{c\rightarrow\infty}\int|g(x)-g(x+c)|dx=2\int|g(x)|dx.$
For general $g$, approximate $g$ by something of the form $g\cdot1_{[-N,N]}$
in $L^{1}$-norm.